# 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found iOS XCode but it worked before

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I tried every possible solution presented on the internet regarding this issue. The weird thing is that running the app worked yesterday and it successfully ran on my phone and I was able to Archive it so I can publish it. But when I checked today to take mockup screenshots, the build gives the `Flutter.h` not found error.

**I tried**

1. pod deintegrate, pod install, pod update, etc
2. Removing cache
3. Moving project files to another project
4. Removing podfile
5. flutter clean, pub get, upgrade, doctor, etc
6. Removing `Flutter.podspec`

The only solution I have yet to try is updating XCode and this is because I don't have enough storage for some reason (I have 40GB and update is 12GB)

**The full error:**

```
Lexical or Preprocessor issue

    Flutter/Flutter.h file not found

        In file included from Users/name/Developer/projectName/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:7:
```